# Text invisible until interacted with

Tags: ios, css

I am having an issue with iOS and text backgrounds.

I have the following text:

```
<h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
```

with this CSS applied to make the text filled with a gradient:

```
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #db6b2a, #ae1a31);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
```

However, I am running into a strange issue on iOS where the text is completely invisible until a user actualy clicks where it should be, at which point it then seems to load. I've tried adding color fallbacks to no success, the only thing that seemed to work was removing the google font that I am using which resulted in it loading fine.

Here is a link to the issue live: https://swillis.co.uk/test

As can be seen on a pc, the "Test" titles load fine, but on iOS they just don't appear.

Thanks

Comment: can you remove the <div id="nav-overlay"></div> and do a test?..

Comment: @marcogomes I've removed it, seems that the issue still persists

Comment: weird that with <div id="nav-overlay"></div> when you open / close menu the content appears

Comment: @marcogomes Yeah it's strange. It appears if you tap and hold roughly where it should be, as it selects the letters even though they're invisible, and then when you tap off and scroll it just appears...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve this in the end. The issue seemed to be a mixture of things, firstly; I removed the pseudo clearfix from my text (not sure why this helped but I still had the issue if this remained), and secondly a removed `display: table;` and set the titles back to inline block. I had to then come up with a workaround to stop content wrapping next to my titles, so I created a simple containing block element.

Answer (score 0):

-webkit-text-fill-color seems not to work on Safari mobile

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-fill-color#Browser_compatibility

Comment: The issue is on iOS Chrome too